sisl: is it possiple to extract band structure from external cells instead of created by sisl.geometry using Class sisl.physics.BandStructure
As for class sisl.physics.BandStructure(parent, point, division, name=None), could we make external cells into objects or array_like things which can be read by sisl.physics.BandStructure?
By the way,here is from the sisl document:
parent:object or array_like
An object with associated parentcell and parent.rcell or an array of floats which may be turned into a SuperCell

Yes, you can basically put anything in the BandStructure, as long as it has some attributes that understands lattice vectors etc.
But your question is extremely generic, what exactly are you aiming for?
